# Detect async script load in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension that needs to examine elements in the DOM. I'm currently trying to solve cases where scripts are added to the DOM after `document.onload` has fired, and those scripts add more elements to the DOM, and I want to look at those elements. Sometimes the elements are in a subframe, and sometimes the script adds them with `document.write`. Yeah, I know, I know.

The main issue currently seems to be that I can't detect whether a script has loaded already. If it hasn't loaded, I can safely attach a listener to `script.onload`, but if it *has* already loaded, `onload` will not fire.

In several other spots I do things like check `readyState` to see if a document is already ready. If it is, I execute my code, and if it is not, I attach an onload listener. However, async scripts in Chrome do not seem to have a readyState despite references to such a property in several SO answers.

So is there any way to figure out if an async script is already loaded? Since this is Chrome-specific, it doesn't need to be cross-browser compatible. Is there some way to use MutationObserver to reliably attach an onload listener for *every* script and track its state manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, why are you making it more difficult for yourself? Why track scripts' `onload` with MutationObserver, when you can just track actual nodes being added?

Answer (score 0):

To detect the scripts which are loaded on the DOM, retrieve all the script tags:

```
document.querySelectorAll('script');
```

This returns an array of scripts loaded on the DOM. Calling .length on the array will show you how many scripts are loaded. And you can reference these scripts via their .src or other attributes to do things like getting their child or sibling elements.

Comment: That doesn't tell you if scripts with the `async` property have actually been downloaded and executed. That's what the `script.onload` event is for, but it has the problems outlined in my question. Thanks, though!

Comment: You could wait for the page to load, until you can safely assume that all the async scripts have finished loading and filter to get only the async scripts. Then write cases for each async script.onload event so that when you refresh the page, you should be able to catch all of the onload events and handle each async script.